# Initramfs unpacking failed: read error + keyboard not working during ArchLinux boot

Tags: linux, boot, keyboard, arch-linux

Recently installed ArchLinux via AnarchyLinux, mounting it's root partition in my /dev/sda6 and it's boot at /dev/sda2, which is the EFI partition i also use for Windows.
However, when trying to boot, while my keyboard works on GRUB, i will receive this error message when it tries to boot Arch:

[image: IMG:]

Worse than that, my keyboard will not work following that, so i couldn't try any of the possible solutions i found online. How may i be able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the initramfs-linux.img and initramfs-linux-fallback.img being missing. For some reason on my computer when I install GRUB2 as my bootloader it removes all files in the current dir (and I install it in /boot with my linux and initramfs images.) Just try reinstalling the linux kernel from a live CD or USB in chroot with `pacman -S linux`. It's a simple fix that worked when my pc did this the first time, it took me a few hours to realize those files were missing.